# In Nuxtjs 3, how can i modify the runtimeConfig based on the request domain?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am building a multidomain site with nuxt 3.

I'm trying to load a different runtimeConfig based on the user request domain, is that possible?

For example, if the user is in mydomain.es

```
{
    privateToken : "XXXXXXXXX",
    public : {
        googleanalytics_id : 'xxxxx'
    }
}
```

If the user is in mydomain.fr

```
{
    privateToken : "YYYYYYYYYY",
    public : {
        googleanalytics_id : 'yyyyy'
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using SSR or SSG?

Comment: @kissu I'm using SSR

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do this, it is not very elegant, but it works...

at: *plugins/configByDomain.server.ts*

```
import { loadConfig } from '../config/SiteConfig'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async nuxtApp => {
    const domain = useRequestHeaders().host.split(':')[0];
    const SiteConfig = await loadConfig(domain);        
    // to make the object writable
    nuxtApp.ssrContext.runtimeConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nuxtApp.ssrContext.runtimeConfig));    
    Object.assign(nuxtApp.ssrContext.runtimeConfig, SiteConfig);
})
```